# add transparent table view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xcode4, uisearchbar

i am building an application and i want to implement search view controller. I build the table view controller with the search bar to it. My search controller is working fine. but I want to when the user click the search button: the controller is showing from the current view controller with transparency. Exactly like facebook search on iphone application.

i tried this code:

```
SearchAllViewController *search= [[SearchAllViewController alloc] init];
search.view.backgroundColor= [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];

search.from=tabSelected;

[self.view addSubview:search.view];
```

my search controller is showing with the transparency but the value "from" is not set, and so i had no result !! but when using this code, it is set but the transparency is not:

```
 UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

 SearchAllViewController *search = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"search"];
search.view.backgroundColor= [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];

search.from=tabSelected;

[self.view addSubview:search.view];
```

any help please ???